Getting singular matrices for lid driven cavity problem
I was trying to solve the lid driven cavity problem using the galerkin method with SUPG stabilization. I was using GMRES method as my solver and I am also getting a solution. And the solution looks correct too. I compared my results with Ghia's results and the solution matches perfectly for all the reynold numbers (upto 5000). But, the issue is my stiffness matrix has a determinant of zero. That must probably mean that my matrices are singular. And I cant figure out why I am getting singular matrices. I have checked the code a number of times, checked the way I applied boundary conditions but I couldnt find out the issue. I was hoping you guys could help me out.
Also, I also solved the flow over a cylinder problem and even here, I get singular matrices but inspite of that when using gmres method, I am getting a reasonable solution. My pressure contour and streamlines match closely with the results from other sources.
I am writing the code on my own in julia using the mixed finite element formulation, galerkin method with both SUPG and LSIC stabilization and my mesh has normal quadrilateral elements with linear shape functions. I am not using LBB stable elements.
Thank you in advance for your suggestions !
Edit: Sorry, I forgot to mention, I am solving the incompressible navier stokes equation.

What are the governing equations?

I am solving an incompressible navier stokes equation in 2d, so momentum equations in 2D and a continuity equation. I am solving a time dependent problem

Depending on the prescribed boundary conditions, the matrix can be rank deficient by one. This is basically equivalent to pressure being unique up to a constant.

But, I have fixed the pressure at one point.

Determinants are a poor way to check singularity, since they are badly scaled. For instance, computing the determinant of $0.1I$ in Float64 (double precision) returns zero for dimension $n\geq 324$, because of underflow.
Check the condition number of that matrix, instead.

Oh yess, Thats probably the reason why I dont get zero when I use less elements, but when I have many elements,(large matrices) I get determinant zero. I checked the condition number and its high. But, I am not sure what value indicates an ill conditioned matrix

Any discretization of a differential operator will have a large condition number. This is a feature of the problem, not your implementation.

Also, I checked whether the inverse for my matrix exists or not, and Julia returns that the "Inverse of this matrix exists".

Concerning why the GMRES finds a solution even if the matrix is singular (or nearly so), GMRES is able to find solutions of singular systems, under some conditions on the range and null space of the matrix (see "GMRES On (Nearly) Singular Systems").
